# PHP object inheritance : how to access parent attributes?

Tags: php, object, inheritance

I wrote this little test script for PHP object inheritance :

```
<?php

class A {
    protected $attr;

    public function __construct($attr) {
        $this->$attr = $attr;
    }

    public function getAttr() {
        return $this->attr;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

$b = new B(5);
echo $b->getAttr();
```

This displays nothing!
Why doesn't it display `5`?
Isn't class B supposed to be like class A?

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
$this->$attr = $attr;
```

you assign here to `$this->{5}` (the value of `$attr`).

Write, to address the property:

```
$this->attr = $attr;
//     ^------ please note the removed `$` sign
```

---

To notice what is going on in such cases, try to dump your object: `var_dump($b);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm very well aware about that, but sometimes you just fail to see a typo, even after checking 10 times...

Comment: Just because sleep doesn't... ^^

Answer (score 2):

You are using [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) instead of accessing the variable directly

```
 $this->$attr = $attr;
        ^
        |----- Remove This
```

With

```
 $this->attr = $attr;
```

Comment: Wooow! I was very disapointed, but now I feel like an idiot! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Leave the system , Play some games GOW is nice .. Take a nap then continue programming ... This fix most similar programming  errors